# How to output ANTLR grammar build to screen (e.g. to JOptionPane like ANTLRworks CTRL-r)

Tags: java, reflection, build, antlr, grammar

I can load a grammar file in to my java project (in netbeans) and generate/build my lexer and parser classes, load them via reflection and then parse what I need to parse.

What I would like is a simple example of redirecting the results from the generate/build of the lexer and parser to a string so that I can put the errors to a popup like JOptionPane.
Just like ANTLRworks does when you do CTRL-R (in windows at least) showing Error(123) grammar.g:100:12: ...Warning...etc...

Now I am already using a DiagnosticCollector but this does not always enough details as the CTRL-r in ANTLRworks does. The idea being the user corrects the grammar in order to correct the mistake.

Here's a snippet of my code

```
            Tool tool = new Tool(new String[]{userDir + grammarPath + grammarName + ".g"});
            //tool.setOutputDirectory(userDir + grammarPath );
            tool.process();
            if(tool.getNumErrors()>0) {
                errors=true;
                unableToLoadGrammar_AddLine("1. Detected "+tool.getNumErrors()+" Error(s)"+tool.toString()+"\n");
            }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call `org.antlr.tool.ErrorManager`'s `setErrorListener` method:

```
public class ToolTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {


        org.antlr.Tool tool = new org.antlr.Tool(new String[] { "GrammarWithErrors.g" });

        final ArrayList<String> messages = new ArrayList<String>();

        ErrorManager.setErrorListener(new ANTLRErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void warning(Message msg) {
                messages.add("Warning: " + msg.toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void info(String msg) {
                messages.add("Info: " + msg.toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void error(ToolMessage msg) {
                messages.add("Tool Error: " + msg.toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void error(Message msg) {
                messages.add("General Error: " + msg.toString());
            }
        });

        tool.process();

        System.out.println("Done processing...");

        for (String msg : messages) {
            System.out.println(msg);
        }
    }
}
```

Passing a bad grammar to the code above produces the following output:

```
Done processing...
General Error: error(100): GrammarWithErrors.g:1:14: syntax error: antlr: MismatchedTokenException(74!=52)
Tool Error: error(150):  grammar file GrammarWithErrors.g has no rules
General Error: error(100): GrammarWithErrors.g:82:7: syntax error: assign.types: NoViableAltException(0@[])
```

Note that `Tool` still operates directly on `System.err` and `System.out`. If you want to handle *everything* coming out of `Tool`, you'll have to call `System.setErr` and `System.setOut` as well.